# installing python3.11 and libraries (numpy, matplotlib, scipy) on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, apt

I want to upgrade the version of python, numpy, matplotlib, and scipy that I am using on a Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, to mirror the versions that I have on my laptop.

Running `apt list --installed` reveals that the following packages (amongst many other python ones) were installed via `apt-get` when the desktop was set up for me:

```
python3-matplotlib-inline/jammy,jammy,now 0.1.3-1 all [installed]
python3-matplotlib/jammy,now 3.5.1-2build1 amd64 [installed]
python3-numpy/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 1:1.21.5-1ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3-scipy/jammy,now 1.8.0-1exp2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3.10-dev/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.10.12-1~22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
python3.10-minimal/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 3.10.12-1~22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

so in particular the last two show that I am running python 3.10.12.

In order to upgrade to python 3.11 I ran

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
$ sudo apt install python3.11-full
```

This gave me bare python, but I'm now having trouble upgrading my libraries, which I would like to manage through pip. In particular I get

```
$ pip install numpy --upgrade
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (1.26.4)
```

and similar when I try to upgrade matplotlib - because those packages are already installed, pip doesn't want to touch them.

Is there a way I can install the new packages on my system and "point" my installation of python 3.11 at them? Ideally I would like to have it system wide and not use virtual environments (mainly because I don't understand them, and I just want to be able to call my scripts from anywhere).

As a bare minimum I would like to know how to upgrade to matplotlib 3.8.2 and import it when running a python 3.10 kernel instead of the current mpl 3.5.1, but ideally upgrade everything.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this is using virtual environments which you can create to follow the specific conditions and dependencies you want 
You can create multiple environments, with different python versions and packages with specified versions 
There're many ways to do that, I especially like
[Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge), it's a great free solution for python version and environment management 
It supports linux, windows and OSX. 
Simple to install and use. 
Installation instructions from the readme:

```
curl -L -O "https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh"
bash Miniforge3-$(uname)-$(uname -m).sh
```

Example, create an environment called "myenv" with python 3.11 and numpy, matplotlib and scipy:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.11 numpy matplotlib scipy
```

To use the environment use:

```
conda activate myenv
python main.py
```

It's also supported by IDEs like Visual Studio Code which is also available on [Ubuntu](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux)

Answer (score 0):

Check which python you use, probably bundled with system one. Create virtual environment for with installed python 3.11 (python -m venv directory_name), activate it and use pip from venv. From my experience this is the easiest way to use desired python version on ubuntu.

Comment: For me python and python3 alias to the system one, 3.10.12. As I said I don't really understand virtual environments, but if this is the only way forward then I'll use it. Once I create a venv in a directory, is it recursive in all subdirectories? And do I only have to do it once and whenever I call python from one of those subdirectories it goes into the venv?

Comment: You need to activate venv each time you want to use it, source script activate in venv bin directory (see https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#create-and-use-virtual-environments). Activation script changes paths, python points to venv interpreter, command deactivate reverses operation. You can add venv activation to login script, or define alias.